# iOS: storing thumbnail images in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, uiimage

I need to take some images from the iPhone / iPad photo library from within my app and store them in a Core Data entity, and display them as small thumbnail images (48x48 pixels) in a UITableViewCell, and about 80x80 pixels in a detail UIView. I've followed the Recipes sample app, where they use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(value, 0.1)` to convert to NSData and store the bytes inside Core Data, and it doesn't end up taking much space, which is good. But when retrieve the data, using `UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:value];` and display it as a thumbnail image with "Aspect Fit", it looks terrible and grainy. I tried changing the image quality variable in the JPEG compression, but even setting it to 0.9 doesn't help.

Is that normal? Is there a better way to compress the image that doesn't cause so much grainee-ness? Since I just want to show a small thumbnail, and then a slightly bigger thumbnail, I feel Core Data would be great for storing this, since it should (theoretically) also support iCloud. But if it's going to look terrible, then I'll have to reconsider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, are you resizing the image to the right size? Have you tried `UIImagePNGRepresentation()`? That should compress it without losing quality.

Comment: Thanks. I did try both, but the images come out looking terrible in every circumstance. It works fine on an iPhone, but on an iPad, picking an image from the library is huge, and maybe doing an Aspect Fit into a 48x48 thumbnail doesn't look good. What would you recommend as a UIImage resizing algo? Maybe the issue is with that. I'm using this: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

If UIImagePNGRepresentation (which is lossless) is giving you bad images, then the problem is in your image resizing code. Core Data is just giving you what you back what you put in, so if you get bad images out, it's because you put bad images in.

Is one of your iPhone/iPad retina and the other isn't? If so, perhaps the problem is that you don't really want 48x48 pixel images, you want 48x48 point (which means you'll need 2x images 96x96 for retina quality display).